Running behave/selenium in a Docker Container
I have built a Docker container, from which to run behave/selenium tests.
The Docker image is based on Oracle Linux 9, and it includes:
/bdds/driver/chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f2e025eddae123f36f6263096ae49-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#1052})

 /usr/lib64/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --version
Chromium 122.0.6261.128 Fedora Project

I have an environment.py file, which sets up the driver:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from lib import ohaitestutl as ohai

def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    base_url = ohai.config_property(config_section='url', config_property='base_url')
    context.base_url = base_url
    options = Options()
    headless_browser = context.config.userdata.get('headless')
    if headless_browser and headless_browser.lower() == 'true':
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        context.headless = True
    else:
        context.headless = False
    context.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    context.driver.maximize_window()

def after_scenario(context, scenario):
    # Close the browser session after each scenario
    if context.driver:
        context.driver.quit()

Installed to the container is a bdds.sh script:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# D-Bus initialization command
DBUS=$(ps -ef | grep "dbus-daemon" | grep -v grep)
if [ -z "${DBUS}" ]
then
  mkdir -p /run/dbus
  dbus-daemon --system &
fi
export PATH=$PATH:/bdds/driver:/usr/lib64/chromium-browser
echo behave -D headless=true features/foreg_login.feature
behave -D headless=true features/foreg_login.feature

When executed there is a delay of a minute or so, and then I get this:
PS C:\Development\CICD\UITests> docker run --name TBDDS bdds
behave -D headless=true features/foreg_login.feature

Feature: Login credentials validation for front office registration 
HOOK-ERROR in before_scenario: WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x55a3ff7ff4e3 <unknown>
#1 0x55a3ff52ec76 <unknown>
#2 0x55a3ff557d78 <unknown>
#3 0x55a3ff554029 <unknown>
#4 0x55a3ff592ccc <unknown>
#5 0x55a3ff59247f <unknown>
#6 0x55a3ff589de3 <unknown>
#7 0x55a3ff55f2dd <unknown>
#8 0x55a3ff56034e <unknown>
#9 0x55a3ff7bf3e4 <unknown>
#10 0x55a3ff7c33d7 <unknown>
#11 0x55a3ff7cdb20 <unknown>
#12 0x55a3ff7c4023 <unknown>
#13 0x55a3ff7921aa <unknown>
#14 0x55a3ff7e86b8 <unknown>
#15 0x55a3ff7e8847 <unknown>
#16 0x55a3ff7f8243 <unknown>
#17 0x7fa57fa82812 start_thread

My Dockerfile:
# =============================================================================
# Selenium Python BDDS Automated Testing
# Date: 25 Mar 2024
#
# This docker file must be run via the BDDS docker_build.sh script.
# =============================================================================

# Stage 1: Use Oracle Linux 9 base image
FROM oraclelinux:9

# Update package lists
RUN dnf update -y
# Enable EPEL repository for Chromium
RUN yum -y update && yum -y install epel-release 
RUN yum -y install chromium

# Install D-Bus package
RUN yum install -y dbus dbus-daemon

# Start D-Bus server at container startup
CMD ["dbus-daemon", "--system"]

# Install dependencies
RUN dnf install -y --setopt=timeout=60000 python3.11 python3-pip wget unzip vim nss-tools libX11

# Create a directory for the bdds framework files and features
RUN mkdir -p /bdds/driver
WORKDIR /bdds/driver

# Deploy the Selenium Chrome driver
COPY chromedriver_linux64.zip /bdds/driver 
RUN unzip -o chromedriver_linux64.zip

RUN python3.11 -m ensurepip
RUN python3.11 -m pip install behave

WORKDIR /bdds
# Install the required Python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /bdds/
RUN python3.11 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the run.sh script
COPY run.sh /etc
COPY bdds.sh /bdds
RUN chmod 755 /bdds/bdds.sh

COPY bdds_temp.zip /bdds/bdds.zip
RUN unzip -o bdds.zip

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /bdds

# Set execute permissions for bash scripts.
RUN chmod 755 /bdds/*.sh
RUN chmod 755 /etc/run.sh


ENTRYPOINT ["/bdds/bdds.sh"]

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

It's hard to know precisely what the problem is but I suspect that you do not have compatible versions of Chrome and ChromeDriver on the image or that there are missing dependencies.
Here's a simplified Dockerfile:
FROM oraclelinux:9

RUN dnf update -y && \
    dnf install -y \
        wget \
        unzip \
        python3.11 \
        python3-pip \
        dbus-x11 \
        gtk3 \
        nss \
        atk \
        at-spi2-atk \
        cups-libs \
        libdrm \
        libxkbcommon \
        libXcomposite \
        libXdamage \
        libXrandr && \
    dnf clean all

RUN wget -q -O chrome-linux64.zip https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/121.0.6167.85/linux64/chrome-linux64.zip && \
    unzip chrome-linux64.zip && \
    rm chrome-linux64.zip && \
    mv chrome-linux64 /opt/chrome/ && \
    ln -s /opt/chrome/chrome /usr/local/bin/ && \
    wget -q -O chromedriver-linux64.zip https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/121.0.6167.85/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip && \
    unzip -j chromedriver-linux64.zip chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver && \
    rm chromedriver-linux64.zip && \
    mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin/

WORKDIR /bdds

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY bdds.sh .
COPY features ./features

RUN chmod 755 bdds.sh

CMD ["./bdds.sh"]

IMHO the most important component of this is ensuring that you have consistent and compatible versions of Chrome and ChromeDriver. Chrome also has a bunch of dependencies that need to be installed otherwise the browser won't launch.
Here's the content of my test setup:
├── bdds.sh
├── Dockerfile
├── features
│   ├── open_browser.feature
│   └── steps
│       └── browser_steps.py
└── requirements.txt

 requirements.txt
behave==1.2.6
selenium==4.19.0

 open_browser.feature
Feature: Open web browser
  Scenario: Visit Google
    Given I have a web browser
    When I navigate to "http://www.google.com"
    Then I can see the Google search page

 browser_steps.py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from behave import given, when, then

@given('I have a web browser')
def step_impl(context):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    
    context.browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

@when('I navigate to "{url}"')
def step_impl(context, url):
    context.browser.get(url)

@then('I can see the Google search page')
def step_impl(context):
    assert "Google" in context.browser.title
    context.browser.quit()

 bdds.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dbus-uuidgen > /var/lib/dbus/machine-id
mkdir -p /var/run/dbus
dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/dbus-1/system.conf --print-address

chrome --version
chromedriver --version

behave

I'm not convinced that the DBUS commands are strictly required but they do suppress a few warning messages, so happy to leave them in. The commands to get the versions of Chrome and ChromeDriver can also be excised. Just wanted to confirm that they have a consistent version.

This can be updated to use an environment file.
 environment.py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")

    context.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    context.driver.maximize_window()

def after_scenario(context, scenario):
    if context.driver:
        context.driver.quit()

 browser_steps.py
from behave import given, when, then

@given("I have a web browser")
def step_impl(context):
    pass

@when('I navigate to "{url}"')
def step_impl(context, url):
    context.driver.get(url)

@then("I can see the Google search page")
def step_impl(context):
    assert "Google" in context.driver.title
    context.driver.quit()


Thanks, I'll take a look, based on your feedback. I included DBUS, because I was getting another error, which seemed to imply there was a dependency.

Hello datawookie. I have been working through the problem based on your example.  The main problem seems to be caused by the use of the features/environment.py file.
If I move the logic to a step file, the problem goes away. Somewhat disappointing, as it works fine on Windows desktop. I am testing via Rancher, so I am not sure whether that's a factor. I have a Linux box in my office, so I may just see if it behaves differently on there. I'll update further when I have finished looking.

Aha! I was working on Linux. But it really should not make a difference. I've updated my answer to use an environment.py file.

Thanks for the update - interesting.  I am just about to check it out on Linux Mint. Maybe it is something to do with  Rancher on Windows, which sits on top of WSL2.

Hello datawookie. It wasn't Rancher after all. I was missing this line in my original code, within environment.py:
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
A big thanks for your assistance on this.

Superb! Great news.
